# How to get list of Web forms in a solution using visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013 for developing web project. I want a complete list of web forms which are showing in my solution.

Any short key or option using in visual studio which is showing it. please help me.

Comment: What do you mean? Solution Explorer at the right side shows the entire list of webforms.

Comment: Yes Solution Explorer

Comment: What about it? You're not able to see it?

Comment: He want to see all file with extension .aspx

Comment: i want to that list into excel, word, notepad etc.

Comment: Then you simply type dir /s *.aspx in windows command prompt.

Comment: command window showing this error 'Command "dir" is not valid'

Comment: Go to windows run>type "cmd" Enter

Answer (score 0):

- Open Windows Explorer and search for what you want
- When the search results populate, select all (Ctrl + A)
- Hold the Shift key and Right Click on the search results
- Select "Copy as Path" (this option only shows up when you hold shift before the right click)
- Paste into excel or word or notepad